# How to Center Align Two Elements With Different Widths Relative to The Parent While Aligned Left With Same Indentation

Tags: css, flexbox, material-ui

I'm using Material UI but this might be a matter of just knowing how to achieve it with Flexbox. Something like in the image below. I having a tough time having all 3 lines aligned the same way on different widths.
[image]

So far I have:

```
<Grid container justify="center">
  <Grid xs={7}>
    <Grid item container direction="column">
      <Grid container justify="flex-start">
        <p>
         Please check the items in the list below and mark them complete.
       </p>
      </Grid>

      <Grid container justify="center">
        Icon
      </Grid>
      <Grid>
        <ul>
         <li>List item</li>
         <li>List item</li>
        </ul>
      </Grid>
    </Grid>
  </Grid>
</Grid>
```

Appreciate any guidance, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some of your grids don't specify if they're containers or items, or lack items, and the dom could be simplified a bit. Maybe something like this? (the inline style is to remove the normal spacing to the left of the list so it looks more like your image, but you should probably properly style your lists and remove it).

```
<Grid container justify="center">
    <Grid xs={7} item container direction="column">
        <Grid item>
            <p>
                Please check the items in the list below and mark them complete.
            </p>
        </Grid>
        <Grid container item justify="center">
            <Grid item>Icon</Grid>
        </Grid>
        <Grid item>
            <ul style={{paddingLeft: 0, listStyle: 'none'}}>
                <li>List item</li>
                <li>List item</li>
            </ul>
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. So I might have complicated the markup while troubleshooting but with the above my main issue is still there. As I hover over the container (dev tools) with xs={7}, it has equal amount of empty space on each side which is good but because the sentence does not take full width of the container, it does not look centered which again I can deal with but. when I resize the window, list is not always aligned with that "Please check...." text, at smaller screen sizes it shows lesser space and so not aligned with that text on top. Hope I'm making sense

Comment: I do understand text width does not grow with the column so its not going to look centered but guess for the same reason the rest of the elements will not look aligned...hmm

Comment: if all items were aligned center, I would not have this issue but it's the left alignment on element that is causing this issue. Not sure what is the best way to handle it

Comment: I think I get better now what you are trying to do. The "Please check.." line needs to be centered, yet the list needs to be aligned to the left with that first line, on a resizable grid, that potentially can be very wide (on big devices). Doesn't sound achievable with those constrains. The main issue is, if the first line needs to be centered, the list has no way to know where to align left (no idea where the first line begins), unless you manually set some margin using javascript, and that sounds like a terrible idea.

Comment: You need to get to a compromise; you can either center the first line and let the list align wherever it can, or you could set a maximum width to the grid instead of xs={7}. You could chose an arbitrary value that looks good enough from that size to smaller sizes, and constrain the grid so it never goes beyond that limit.

Comment: Thanks for your input, guess that's what I'll have to do.